# How to create a new array containing data from an other array in react native?

Tags: arrays, loops, react-native

How do I create a new array from another array

my array is data1

```
this.state = {
    data1: [
        {'x':'%20', 'y':11, 'z':'sunday'},
        {'x':'%30', 'y':21, 'z':'monday'},
        {'x':'%40', 'y':31, 'z':'tuesday'}          
    ],
    data2: [],
}
```

and i want to create data2, that look like this

```
data2: [
    {'x':'%20-(11)-sunday'},
    {'x':'%30-(21)-monday'},
    {'x':'%40-(31)-tuesday'}
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
  data1=  [
   {'x':'%20', 'y':11, 'z':'sunday'},
   {'x':'%30', 'y':21, 'z':'monday'},
   {'x':'%40', 'y':31, 'z':'tuesday'}          
  ]
    
  data2 = data1.map((item)=> ({x: Object.values(item).join('-')}))
  console.log("data2", data2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```
const data2 = data1.map(value => ({ x: `${value.x}-(${value.y})-${value.z}` }))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below function to convert data1 array to data2 array:

```
createCustomArray() {
   this.state.data1.forEach(function (item) {
      this.state.data2.push({'x': item.x+'-('+item.y+')-'+item.z});
   });
}
```

Comment: This is agains the guidelines. You are mutating the state this wont rerun the component lifecycle.

Comment: As @OzgrMan is referring the data2 array within state, its essential to append data to data2 array within state. Hence it is a good practice to create a custom array whenever you get data1 by just calling that function